# How to download a chrome extension without installing it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been trying many methods posted in the past but no one does work.
Is there a way to download a chrome extensione without installing it ?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to redirect you to this page: [Google Forums Link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/g02KlhK12fU)

It has worked for me, i myself have tried it on this extension: [Audio EQ](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/audio-eq/lfafdlnjaliaghpjdajmlcnnblkgcefh)
I hope it works for you (:
if you want my end result (the .crx) just message me (:

EDIT:
I had to install a chrome extension on a machine not connected to the internet. I didn't download the .crx file, but I did find a way to install:

- With a computer connected to the internet, install the extension from the extension page: need 10 rep for 2+ links/
- Navigate to the extension source code. In XP this is found at: C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application
  Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\
- You should see a version folder (ie. "0.0.21_0"). Copy this folder and move it on the machine you want to install on.
- Open up chrome on the disconnected machine and go to Wrench -> Tools -> Extensions
- Click the + next to Developer mode to display the developer options
- Click 'Pack extension...' and choose the version folder as the root directory. Leave the private key file blank. This will create a .crx
  file in the version folder along with a private key as if you were
  the developer.
- Open the .crx file in chrome to install

This should install the extension on a computer without connection to the internet.

Comment: Could you quote the relevant part of that huge thread? Link-only answers are frowned upon on Stack Overflow.

Comment: the Google Forums link is broken now